# Logic Puzzle Question

Tags: puzzle

Suppose there is a vending machine that sells Coke and Sprite. This particular vending
machine has 3 dispensers, one for Coke, one for Sprite, and the last one either dispenses Coke or Sprite at random. There's just 1 problem, all of the labels for the dispensers
have been mixed up and are incorrect! How many times do you have to buy a drink in order
to know definitely which dispenser dispenses what?

My Thinking:

**Pay once:** So I start at the dispenser labeled "Random." I push it and receive a Sprite. This must mean that this dispenser is for Sprite.

**Pay Twice:** Next, I go to the Sprite dispenser and receive a Coke. This must be the Coke dispensers.

Lastly, the last dispenser must be Random!

Does my reasoning make sense for this puzzle?

Comment: Assuming all labels are now incorrect (and haven't just been randomly mixed up) then going for the dispenser labelled "Random" first seems like a good strategy. But how do you know the second dispenser is not the "Random" one?

Comment: Okay, I see your point. What if I start at the "Random" one and bought a drink and it was Sprite, then this has to be Sprite. At the "Sprite" one I should buy two drinks to see if it random? Is that where I should be headed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't go to the second dispenser. Namely, once you've decided that "Random" is indeed Sprite, "Sprite" *must* be Coke. (Otherwise, "Sprite" would be Random, and "Coke" would be Coke, i.e. Coke wouldn't be wrongly labelled.)